# How can I add HTML ASCII codes into menu link items?

Tags: 7, routes

Is there a module or method for adding in HTML ASCII codes into menu item links in Drupal 7?

Currently, I want to make the following a link in my footer menu.

```
&copy; Copyright 1998-2000
```

Comment: Try to edit a template theme 'sites/all/themes/%name_your_default_theme%'

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate a little more? As it stands this answer isn't really suitable for this site. What template do you suggest OP should try editing?

Comment: As side note, the copyright symbol is not part of ASCII codes; it's Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to use CSS and then use :before to insert the copyright symbol.

```
.copyright-block:before {
  content: "\a9";
}
```

Comment: This would mean to be able to alter the CSS class output for the menu link, which is not possible without a module that does it. At that point, it is probably better to use the [Menu HTML](https://drupal.org/project/menu_html) module.

Comment: Menu items have unique classes so it would be easy. Either way, it was just an alternative solution, Menu HTML works fine.

Comment: i like this method as i dont need to install another module.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [Menu HTML](https://drupal.org/project/menu_html).

> This very simple module adds a checkbox to the menu item edit form and allows the admin to add html to the menu item title. The idea is to use this for external links for which you want to display a logo of the visited site or simply to add strong on some words.

Comment: I would say this is the solution the OP is looking for.